# how to print all id names in one loop?

Tags: c, struct

This code is about 'struct' in C..

I created a struct  with the properties name,roll etc.. By using the for-loop I let the user to create the struct objects. they are named as student,employee, faculty

the problem is the objects are created. But I can use them only inside the for-loop. If I want to get the value of all names in main function, it doesn't work. How can I solve it?How do i print all names in the code in only one loop
what will be the logic

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>  
struct student
{
    int std;
    char fee[90];                                 //Collect Data of students
    int rollno;
    char name[15];
    char sub[100];
};
main()
{
    int x;
    printf("******Enter the total number of Student from HOD*******:\n");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    struct student a[x];
    for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter Rollno:\t");
        scanf("%d",&a[x].rollno);
        printf("\nEnter name:\t");
        scanf("%s",&a[x].name);
        printf("\nIs Fee Submitted:\t");
        scanf("%s",&a[x].fee);
        printf("\nEnter Subject name:\t");
        scanf("%s",a[x].sub);
    }
    printf("\n****Display All Student names****");
    for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
    {
        printf("\n%s",a[x].name);
    }   


    //Faculty 
    struct faculty
    {
        char Fname[100];
        char Sname[100];
    };

    int y;
    printf("\n\n********Please HOD enter the total faculty members********\n");
    scanf("%d",&y);
    struct faculty b[y];
    for(int j=0;j<y;j++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter Faculty Member Name:\t");
        scanf("%s",&b[y].Fname);
        printf("\nEnter their Subjects:\t");
        scanf("%s",&b[y].Sname);
    }
    printf("\n****Display all Faculty Member Name****");
    for(int j=0;j<y;j++)
    {
        printf("\n%s",b[y].Fname);
    }

    // Employes
    struct employes
    {
        char ename[100];
        char rank[100];
    };
    int z;
    printf("\n\n********please HOD enter the total no of Employes*******:\n");
    scanf("%s",&z);
    struct employes c[z];
    for(int j=0;j<y;j++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter the Employe name:\t");
        scanf("%s",&c[y].ename);
        printf("\n and enter their ranks:\t");
        scanf("%s",&c[y].rank);

    }
    printf("\n****Display all Employe names****");
    for(int j=0;j<y;j++)
    {
        printf("%s\n",c[y].ename);
    }

}
```

Comment: `scanf("%d",&a[x].rollno);`->`scanf("%d",&a[i].rollno);` and similar across all the looping.

Comment: How do i print all names in the code in only one loop what will be the logic

Comment: Loop through all entries, and print the name field in each: `for(int i=0;i<x;i++) { printf("\n%s",a[i].name); }`

Comment: Somebody did your work of applying decent indentation. Please consider to accept the edit. Please also rethink whether this is the right way for making a question.

Comment: Also: `scanf("%s",&a[x].name);` -> `scanf("%s", a[i].name);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>  
struct student
{
    int std;
    char fee[90];                                 
    int rollno;
    char name[15];
    char sub[100];
};
main()
{
    int x;
    printf("******Enter the total number of Student from HOD*******:\n");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    struct student a[x];
    for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter Rollno:\t");
        scanf("%d",&a[x].rollno);
        printf("\nEnter name:\t");
        scanf("%s",&a[x].name);
        printf("\nIs Fee Submitted:\t");
        scanf("%s",&a[x].fee);
        printf("\nEnter Subject name:\t");
        scanf("%s",a[x].sub);
    }
    printf("\n****Display All Student names****");
    for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
    {
        printf("\n%s",a[x].name);
    }   

    struct faculty
    {
        char Fname[100];
        char Sname[100];
    };

    int y;
    printf("\n\n********Please HOD enter the total faculty members********:\n");
    scanf("%d",&y);
    struct faculty b[y];
    for(int j=0;j<y;j++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter Faculty Member Name:\t");
        scanf("%s",&b[y].Fname);
        printf("\nEnter their Subjects:\t");
        scanf("%s",&b[y].Sname);
    }
    printf("\n****Display all Faculty Member Name****");
    for(int j=0;j<y;j++)
    {
        printf("\n%s",b[y].Fname);
    }

    struct employes
    {
        char ename[100];
        char rank[100];
    };
    int z;
    printf("\n\n********Please HOD enter the total no of Employes*******:\n");
    scanf("%d",&z);            //You used %s instead of %d
    struct employes c[z];
    for(int j=0;j<z;j++)  //You used wrong variable 'y' here
    {
        printf("\nEnter the Employe name:\t");
        scanf("%s",&c[z].ename);  //You used wrong variable 'y' here
        printf("\nEnter their ranks:\t");  
        scanf("%s",&c[z].rank);  //You used wrong variable 'y' here

    }
    printf("\n****Display all Employe names****");
    for(int j=0;j<z;j++)  //You used wrong variable 'y' here
    {
        printf("\n%s",c[z].ename);  //You used wrong variable 'y' here
    }
}
```

Errors:

1. Wrong format specifier used in taking integer input in number of Employees.
2. Wrong loop variable used in all loops of Employee.

Now this code is working. I've pointed out the errors in the comments also.

Answer (score 0):

The loop increases `i` from `0` to some other value `x`.
*(lets say `x` is 5 for this example)*

So `i` has values 0, 1, 2, 3....

But regardless, you only put data into one element of the array: 5
And you keep overwriting that same element over and over again.
And 5 isn't even a valid index!!  The valid indicies are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4.
5 is one-past the end of the array!